# Insert Thumbnails in image

Tags: linux, image, ubuntu, imagemagick, thumbnails

I am creating an exercise for my student and i would like to insert a specific image in another image as a thumbnail on Linux.

The objective is to add an image with specific metadata in another image as thumbnail.

Thanks you for your help

Thibaud

Comment: Please give an example - we don't have your specific image with specific metadata, nor do we have the image to insert it into nor any idea where it should be inserted or what size either image is.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you for your answer. I just want to insert an image A as thumbnail in image B.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, make a red background image:

```
convert -size 300x200 xc:red bg.png
```

Take a 420x500 picture of Ladram Bay:

[image]

Copyright © [Mark Setchell](http://thesetchells.com) - *Ladram Bay*

resize it and offset from bottom-right corner:

```
convert LadramBay.jpg -resize 80x80 -gravity Southeast -geometry +10+40 bg.png +swap -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thank tour for your answer. I think a need to give an example. Image B hide specific metadata that i have created (coordonate). I want to add this image as thumbnail in image A. My student have to find the coordonate. The solution is to extract the image A  thumbnail with exiftool and search for metadata in image B (image B is the Thumbnail)

Comment: Meta data will be lost in the thumbnail once it is inserted into the background because the result is a totally new image. You can copy the meta data from the thumbnail to the final result using external tools such as Exiftool. But you cannot save the meta data from the original thumbnail image into its region in the final image.

Comment: That's precisely why I asked you to be more specific in your question!